# Wiris Plugin in Ckeditor Dont generate formula image

Tags: ckeditor, wiris

i am using wiris ckeditor plugin (asp.net) ,when click on Accept Button (in Wiris Formula Plugin),in (showimage.aspx) page, an Error is showing to me that formula is null 
when enter the
 http://localhost:9454/Admin/ckeditor/plugins/ckeditor_wiris/integration/showimage?formula=5566227c791392b1bce2a0c0553053aa.png

address i get this status
status  "warning"

please help me,
thanks.